# mysql query to select all objectives of a goal and those objective which are done

Tags: mysql

goal id   total occurance of goal id  total occurance when status is 1

1                        5                            3

This is schema of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `goal_objectives` (
  `objective_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `objective_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `objective_description` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `goal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `objective_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
);

select goal_id,  count(objective_status)as objective_done
from goal_objectives
where objective_status='1' group by goal_id;


select goal_id,count(goal_id) as total_current_goals 
from goal_objectives
group by goal_id
order by goal_id DESC ;
```

I just want to show the combine result of these two queries.

Individually it returns required result but when i try to merge them is does not work 
See the output in the link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NrOM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select goal_id, count(*) as total_current_goals,
       sum( objective_status = 1 ) as objective_done
from goal_objectives
group by goal_id
order by goal_id desc ;
```

Note that `objective_status` is a number.  The comparison value should be a *number*, not a *string*.

Comment: Thank you @gordon-linoff